# Can't get code from bbc basic working

Tags: basic, bbc-micro

```
  440 DEFPROCsave
  450 phonenos=OPENUP("Phonenos")
  470 PRINT
  480 FOR j= 1 TO counter
  490       PRINT#phonenos,contact{(j)}.name$,contact{(j)}.phone$,contact{(j)}.email$
  500   FOR f = 1 TO 10
  510     PRINT#phonenos,contact{(j)}.response%(1,f)
  520   NEXT f
  530   
  540 NEXT j
  550 CLOSE#phonenos
  560 PRINT "Data saved."
  570 ENDPROC
```

Code to save details from database I'm trying to save what i have entered to a file but the error INVALID CHANNEL AT LINE 490 APPEARS/

Comment: Whoa; a blast from the past. Define "not working". #390 has an issue, #490 has an issue, there may be others.

Comment: Thanks yea 490 not working

Comment: Have you verified that `phonenos` opens and is a readable db file?

Comment: no sorry how do u do that?

Comment: Any body know how to get this working where it can create and save contacts to a file?

Comment: 370 DEFPROCcreate
      380 counter = counter + 1
      390 INPUT"Name " contact{(counter)}.name$
  400 INPUT"Phone number ",contact{(counter)}.phone$
  410 INPUT"Email address ", contact{(counter)}.email$
  420 ENDPROC
  430 
  440 DEFPROCsave
  450 phonenos=OPENOUT("Phonenos")
  470 PRINT
  480 FOR j= 1 TO counter
  490   PRINT#phonenos,contact{(j)}.name$,contact{(j)}.phone$,contact{(j)}.email$
  500   FOR f = 1 TO 10
  510     PRINT#phonenos,contact{(j)}.response%(1,f)
  520   NEXT f
  530   
  540 NEXT j
  550 CLOSE#phonenos
  560 PRINT "Data saved."
  570 ENDPROC

Comment: The **Alpha BASIC (AB)** we sometimes have to use would differs from your **BBC Micro**. In **AB**, the call would be `OPEN #1,"Phonenos",INPUT`. It is hard to find documentation on these, but testing your File Handle might be what you need to search for.

Comment: @DaveNewton Could you please tell me the issues?

Comment: #490 had those two tick marks in the text. #390 is no longer listed.

Comment: 390 INPUT"Name " contact{(counter)}.name$

Comment: what do u mean by tick marks?

Comment: There were two backticks before the `PRINT`. Don't you need a comma after the string on 390?

Comment: Yes thanks, but can't see any backticks

Comment: PRINT#phonenos,contact{(j)}.name$,contact{(j)}.phone$,contact{(j)}.email$

Answer (score 1):

If your error is on line 490, one of two things is likely happening.

1. Your FILEHANDLE for `phonenos` did not open.

   > You could be attempting to access the file from a bad location, it may not exist, or it could be write protected.
2. Your `contact` array is referencing an invalid index item.

   > Is `counter` going outside the range of the array? Is this a zero (0) or one (1) based array?

Comment: I do not know if `contact{(j)}` is a valid indexer. Here, you are the expert and not me.

Comment: We have an **AlphaBASIC** manual here, but I haven't found any online sources of information. Luckily, I have not had to edit much of that old code (knock on wood).